# How to access component from a module which is imported in app module?

Tags: angular, typescript

We have a project with this hierarchy.

```
app/
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts    <--moduleA and moduleB is imported here  
├── app-routing.module.ts
├── moduleA/
│   ├── moduleA-routing.module.ts
│   ├── moduleA.module.spec.ts
│   ├── moduleA.module.ts
│   ├── moduleA.component.ts
│   └── moduleA.component.html
├── moduleB/
│   ├── moduleB-routing.module.ts
│   ├── moduleB.module.ts     <-- moduleC is imported here
│   ├── moduleB.component.module.ts
│   ├── moduleB.component.html
│   ├── moduleB.component.ts
|   ├── moduleC/
│   │    ├── moduleC-routing.module.ts
│   │    ├── moduleC.module.ts
│   │    ├── moduleC.component.module.ts
│   │    ├── moduleC.component.html   --> Need to use moduleA component here
│   │    └── moduleC.component.ts
```

`moduleC` is sub module of `moduleB`. We have imported `moduleA` in `AppModule`. Can we access component of `moduleA` in `moduleC` without again importing `moduleA` inside `moduleC`. **In other words, is it necessary to import a module which is already imported in `AppModule` again in child module to use it's component?**.

When I try without importing moduleA again in moduleC, it throws

> "Template parse errors: {{selector name}} is not a known element"

But if it's imported then it's working fine.

Comment: any component of a module if you want to use in another module you will have to import it in that module.

Comment: You probably need to put your component in moduleA `exports` array.

Comment: you need to import buddy, cause app module is the main module, and it is needed to imported there...

Answer (score 0):

Don't import moduleA and moduleB in app.module.ts file.
import moduleA in moduleB.module.ts
And import moduleB in moduleC.module.ts
And finally import moduleC in app.module.ts
Now you can access moduleA component in moduleB and moduleC also.

Answer (score 0):

You should use imports:[ModuleA] and even exports: [ModuleA], for have access to it from outer module